# JS: Return variable set by Promise's then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to return a variable which is set by a Promise's then() in a JS function.
The function is called externally by including the myScript.js file
For eg: 
 **myScript.js**

```
function myFunc(){ 
   var myFieldToReturn; 
   functionThatReturnsPromise().then(function(data){\n
       //The value of "data" is used to perform some operations and 
       //should be returned to the caller of myFunc()
            myFieldToReturn = data + "Hi"; 
   });
   return myFieldToReturn;
}
```

`functionThatReturnsPromise()` is a function defined external to this script and is not modifiable.
Call to `myFunc` is also external and I have no control on the way my return value is used (So, I cannot send back a `promise` as my function's return value).
Any help on would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: There is no way to do this. You will have to modify the signature of the function to either return a `Promise` (preferred) or accept a `callback`

Comment: Then you're pretty much SOL. `myFunc` is asynchronous because `functionThatReturnsPromise` is asynchronous, so the caller of `myFunc` must also be asynchronous. You cannot "synchronise" an asynchronous function.